# Error: Content not allowed in prolog

Tags: android

I know this question has been asked before but I can't find the solution in previous solutions. The error points to the file `Game.java`. The code for that file is very simple:

```
package framework;

public interface Game {
    public Input getInput();

    public FileIO getFileIO();

    public Graphics getGraphics();

    public Audio getAudio();

    public void setScreen(Screen screen);

    public Screen getCurrentScreen();

    public Screen getStartScreen();
}
```

I have used the file several times before without problems. I have updated the manifest file. I have updated Android Studio and all the plug-ins (in fact I have re-installed them). The project was created using Android Studio instead of being imported. I have tried cleaning the project. I just can't see what the problem is. Can you please help?

The location of the problem is

```
G:\AndroidStudioProjects\Marvelous2\app\src\main\res\framework\Game.java
```

Comment: Thank you for the edits. I will try to do better in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't place Java files under the `res` folder, those belong under `src/main/java`. Correct directory for `Game.java` is `src/main/java/framework/Game.java`.

Comment: I didn't place it there. I placed the source code in app--java. The res folder is separate. Is there some way that Android Studio could be placing it in the wrong place? Can you give me any clue as to where to look, please?

Comment: I think it's unlikely that AS put it there. Anyway, move the class file out of the `res` folder.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. I had seen the posts about the `res` folder. However, in the project window it was in the right place and it didn't show up in the `res` folder. However, using Windows Explorer I found that there was a copy in the `res` folder. Deleting it seems to have fixed things (except for bugs in my code). Thanks again.